# How can one reverse the order of a list in Python without using a loop?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

How can one reverse the order of a list in Python without using a loop? There are no other constraints on the solution space.

Comment: `l.reverse()`. It's the *first Google result* for "Python reverse list", *right in the documentation*.

Answer (score 7):

```
a = ['a','b','c']
```

you can try

```
b = a[::-1]
```

It will reverse the list without using loop.

You can use the same trick on any sequence/container/iterable to get item reversed.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you explain how to interpret the bracketed arguments?

Comment: @user1800340 It's Python's [Slice Notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation) :)

Comment: I think I figured it out. 
'list[::x]' 
means step in direction (sign of x) and magnitude x. Hence -1 would mean step backwards with each step being size 1.

Comment: @user1800340 as mentioned by Haidro, it is slice notation of list. you can refer [official docs for list](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list). It will explain everything.

Comment: There are three arguments in slice notation, start, stop and step, if u dont provide by default start will be 0, stop will be -1 means including everything in list, and step is -1 hence start from last element and iterate in reverse.

Comment: @user1800340 See [this link](http://bergbom.blogspot.in/2011/04/python-slice-notation.html) for more explanation.

Answer (score 4):

`list.reverse()`

Whether or not the underlying implementation uses a loop I don't know.

[Datastructures - Python Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Answer (score 2):

This reverse function is inefficient because of the way Python handles lists. However, it's worth understanding because it shows how to use a recursive function to replace a loop in a way that can be adapted to almost any language. (In other words, it doesn't depend on built-in features of Python.) Note that `l[:1]` returns a single-item list containing the first item of `l` and `l[1:]` returns all the remaining items in `l`.

```
>>> def reverse(l):
...     return reverse(l[1:]) + l[:1] if l else l
... 
>>> reverse([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the builtin function `reversed`

```
a = list(reversed(your_list))
```

Comment: @septi Actually, `reversed` returns an iterator, so you need to use `list` to store a list in `a` instead of an iterator.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the change in-place:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> a.reverse()
>>> a
[3, 2, 1]
>>> a[:] = a[::-1]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways:

You can use extended [List Slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation):

```
>>> print [1, 2, 3, 4, 5][::-1]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Or use the built in [`.reverse()`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) function:

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> L.reverse()
>>> print L
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Or use [`reversed()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed), which returns the reversed list - but as an iterator:

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> print reversed(L)
<listreverseiterator object at 0x2c3630>
>>> print list(reversed(L))
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

---

Timing comparisons:

```
$ python -m timeit "L = range(1000)" "L = L[::-1]"
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.8 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit "L = range(1000)" "L.reverse()"
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.13 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit "L = range(1000)" "L = list(reversed(L))"
100000 loops, best of 3: 19.1 usec per loop
```